# How to allow Additional Mailbox Task Flags to show in my "To-Do List"?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, tasks, to-do

## Background:

In my place of work we each have our own mailbox that we use for various tasks. We also have a central shared mailbox that myself and my colleagues access continuously throughout every working day. We each have our own area of work and emails are categorised depending on who the email is for. However, due to the volume of emails that are received in this mailbox, emails are sometimes missed.

## Question:

Is there a way so that when an email is flagged in this additional mailbox, it creates a copy in my own "To-Do List"?

The reason I ask is because when I flag an email in this additional mailbox, I still have to trawl through the mailbox to find the flag. I would like it to copy them to my "To-Do List" because items in here can be shown in the task sidebar and I can then keep an eye on tasks I have left to do a lot easier.